# how to fix resizable column in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image: bugged]

as you can see, vote button and some text got out of div. how to fix it? and how to set a value of width, when column become "adapted"?
code is:

```
div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span2">
                </div>

                <div class="span10">
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ok, i've added min-width:170px, column looks good, but span10 transferred under span2, before span2 become "adapted". here is pic: http://img12.imageshack.us/img12/3479/fi2x.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like extra padding is given to the inner element of span2 which is causing such problem, remove that padding and everything is gonna work fine hopefully!

Another possible solution would be fixing left bar as you want it for always

try

```
position: fixed;
```

I am sure one of the solution will work for you!

Comment: no, it doesnt. fixed atribite makes it floating over all divs(

Comment: bootstrap uses media queries to find out the possibility to place columns (such as your span2 with span10) in a single line according to the screen/browser resolution, when it cant then it comes under the next one.

Comment: have you tried width: auto; rather giving your button min-width ??

Comment: yes, i understand media-queries, and why it is so, but i dont want to edit bootstrap(

Comment: auto for button dont work
full web site you can see here: http://nexus7world.ru/sumdu/

Comment: dear wingsofovnia, i found your .well class has extra/useless padding (19px), remove that and everything will be fine